# Help with the generalized triangle inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

I am reading Visual Complex Analysis and the initial exercise asks to prove:

$$|z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + .... + z_n| \leq |z_1|+|z_2|+ ... + |z_n|$$

Here is how I am proving it.

Let us rewrite $z_i$ st $z_i=x_i+iy_i$. Then $|z_i|=\sqrt{x_i^2+y_i^2}$. And so,

$$|z_1+z_2+z_3 + ... + z_n| \equiv \sqrt{\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2+\left(\sum_i y_i\right)^2}$$

And RHS of inequality:

$$\sum_i |z_i | \equiv \sum_i \sqrt{x_i^2+y_i^2}$$

So we have:

$$\sqrt{\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2+\left(\sum_i y_i\right)^2} \leq \sum_i \sqrt{x_i^2+y_i^2}$$

In rewritten form. Now we have to show that the inequality holds. Square both sides.

$$\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2+\left(\sum_i y_i\right)^2 \leq \sum_i (x_i^2+y_i^2) + 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i^2+y_i^2} \left(\sum_{j=i+1}^n \sqrt{x_j^2+y_j^2} \right) \right)$$

Now I have:

$$2\sum_i x_i \left(\sum_{j=i+1}^n x_j \right) + 2\sum_i y_i \left(\sum_{j+1}y_j \right) \leq 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i^2+y_i^2} \left(\sum_{j=i+1}^n \sqrt{x_j^2+y_j^2} \right) \right) $$

$$\sum_i x_i \left(\sum_{j=i+1}^n x_j \right) + \sum_i y_i \left(\sum_{j+1}^ny_j \right) \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i^2+y_i^2} \left(\sum_{j=i+1}^n \sqrt{x_j^2+y_j^2} \right) \right) $$

And I am stuck here.

Comment: $|z_1+z_2+z_3|\leq |z_1|+|z_2+z_3|\leq |z_1|+|z_2|+|z_3|$ isn't it?

Comment: In other words: use induction...

Comment: Yes. what about completing the proof that I started above? Is it even possible, or is it too cumbersome?

Comment: Well it looks overly complicated to me... If you really want to prove the triangle inequality for complex numbers just assuming the triangle inequality for reals, you may do a similar proof as yours for the case $n=2$ and then use induction.

Comment: got it. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of thinking,

Recall that $|z|^2=z\times \overline z $ 
So \begin{eqnarray*}|z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + .... + z_n|^2
 &=& (z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + .... + z_n)\times \overline{(z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + .... + z_n)}\\
&=&(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+ ... + |z_n|^2) +(\sum_{i<j} z_i\overline {z_j} +\overline {z_i}z_j)\\
&=&(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+ ... + |z_n|^2) +2\sum_{i<j} Re(z_i\overline {z_j})\\
&=&(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+ ... + |z_n|^2) +\sum_{i\neq j} Re(z_i\overline {z_j})\\
&\leq&(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+ ... + |z_n|^2) +\sum_{i\neq j} |z_i\overline {z_j}|\\
&=&(|z_1|+|z_2|+ ... + |z_n|)^2\end{eqnarray*}

Since $|z|>0$ $\forall$ z, square both sides ,you will get your equation.

Comment: Do you mean "take the square root of both sides"?